# How can I limit http method to a Django REST api

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

How can I change the  **api_view** decorator in the Function Based View to Class Based View? My requirement is, I want to limit the HTTP access methods such as GET, POST, PUT etc to a particular API

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return Response({"message": "Got some data!", "data": request.data})
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

Hope someone know the answer .....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `http_method_names` as below and hope you using `ModelViewSet` class.

```
class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use APIView. Methods only you define in class will be permissible.In this only get and post is permissible.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class SnippetList(APIView):
"""
List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
"""
def get(self, request, format=None):
    snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the generic class based views. They only provide the appropriate http method handlers, for example **generics.RetrieveAPIView** only allows GET request. The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes) at  lists the generic views and what methods they support.